# Catching IO exception while reading Object from file

Tags: exception, io

This is my code to save a object in a file

```
public class GestorJogo implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7306138323877410801L;
/**
 * 
 */

private Jogo _jogo;

public void abrir(String nomeFicheiro){
        try{
            ObjectInputStream abre = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nomeFicheiro));
            _jogo = (Jogo) abre.readObject();
            abre.close();
            System.out.println(_jogo);
          }
          catch(IOException e) { System.out.println("io exception");}
          catch(ClassNotFoundException e){ System.out.println("no  class available");}
}
```

}

I get IO exception instead of reading the file. Can someone help me dealing whit that?

Comment: So what's the exception?  Print out the value of `e.toString()` and post here...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I forgot to put one class implementing serializable! Noob mistake. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectInputStream` constructor and the `readObject` can both throw an IO exception. I'd start by setting a breakpoint to determine which line exactly is throwing the exception.

Also verify that `nomeFicheiro` is a correct path and filename combination. If it is just the file name, and not the full path, that could explain what is going on. Make sure the path exists and the filename is at that location.

It looks like you are casting the `Object` type returned from `readObject()` into type `Jogo`. I'm not 100% sure, but does the file and it's content need to map correctly to that custom type? I'd check that as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But I think everything is fine, I just don´t know why when I call the method it catch the IO exception.